# In Firebase, do I really have to download an entire node in order store something?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm using Firebase with the Angular2 package AngularFire2 and am trying to learn how to create new items.

According to the docs:

> Use the push() method to add new items on the list.
>
> ```
> const items = af.database.list('/items');
> items.push({ name: newName });
> ```

In my case, "items" will be a HUGE array. Do I really need to fetch it first and then do a push? Can't I just push without having to download it first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a new child to a location, you need to create a reference to that location. Creating a reference to a location does *not* download all items at that location.

Using the JavaScript SDK for the Firebase Database, this takes:

```
const items = firebase.database().ref('/items');
items.push({ name: newName });
```

On the other hand: creating an AngularFire2 observable *will* download the items at that location. So if you want to add items without downloading the existing data, use the JavaScript SDK for the Firebase Database.

Comment: Hmm. Don't I have to subscribe to the observable before it actually downloads the items?

Comment: That could be. I'm not an Angular2/AngularFire2 expert. But you can check the network tab of your browser to see if/when the data is downloaded. But for certain: the regular JavaScript SDK snippet I shared will add a child without downloading the items. And since AngularFire is built on top of that same SDK, they interoperate perfectly: so the new child will show up in any observables you may have elsewhere in the same page/app.

Comment: The AngularFire2 list and object observables won't download anything until `subscribe` has been called. So there is essentially no difference between the two snippets.

Comment: Good to heard @cartant. And remember: you can always check exactly what the Firebase client sends/receives in the Network tab of your browser. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42181519/209103

Comment: I am using firebase.database().ref but a node refresh is still happening  when an update occurs.