# How much data is transferred with geofire set

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, data-transfer, geofire

How much data is transferred when I send the location to geofire table with 
`geoFire.set("?????", [??.????, ??.????])` after the connection of the browser client has be set up?

- Somekey is a unique id up to 5 digits?
- down to the 4th digit (gives us an accuracy of 11m according to [Measuring accuracy of latitude and longitude](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/measuring-accuracy-of-latitude-and-longitude))

We want to show a client with a fleet in public transport that it isn't really that much - but want to give facts. It would be nice to get the data every 5-10 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see how much data is being transferred:

- open the network tab of your browser
- select the <kbd>WS</kbd> panel to just see web sockets
- find the web socket that connects to your Firebase server
- check the size of the frame that sets the value and the acknowledgement

One example from [the first GeoFire javascript sample](https://geofire.firebaseapp.com/fish1/index.html):

```
{"t":"d","d":{"r":2,"a":"m","b":{"p":"/-Kcj5Z0QMWqWaqO-3bUk","d":{"fish0":{".priority":"rmjhprs42j","g":"rmjhprs42j","l":[-16.130262,153.605347]}}}}}
```

> 149 bytes